# Conditional probability and complementary events

Tags: probability

I'm unsure how to approach this question:

Let A and B be events, and let A` be the complement of A.

Suppose P(A) = 0.4  P(B | A) = 0.5  P(B | A`) = 0.2

Compute P(B)

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to XV, Jared. Hint: $B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A')$.

Answer (score 2):

@Taylor is correct. Consider Event $B$ and $A$ and the Event $B$ and $A'$.
$$B = (B\cap A) \cup (B\cap A')$$

Because $A\cap A' = \varnothing$ meaning $A$ and $A'$ are mutually exclusive, then $$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A')P(A')$$